# How to remotely turn on screen sharing?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, screen-sharing

I recently tried to turn on Internet Sharing for my mac mini, and accidentally hit 'Remote Management' which turns off screen sharing! I have no peripherals - not even a display, but I do have a lot of Apple Laptops. Is there any way to turn it back on if I know the root/admin username and password?!

I also tried booting in target disk mode - both machines are running mountain lion, and connected through a firewire cord (with a thunderbolt adapter on one side). When I boot my machine in target disk mode I just get the firewire logo bouncing around, never see the others image.

Comment: Boot the Mac Mini into Target Disk Mode, and on your Mac Laptop, boot up, press and hold ALT/Option button until you can see both HDD (one the local HDD, and one the Target disk mode) and choose that one to boot from it. This way you are using your Mac Laptop as a screen for the Mac Mini. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have any peripherals - any idea how to boot the mac mini in TDM? @Darius

Comment: To boot Mac Mini to TDM - press and hold T (when booting up the Mac Mini)... of course the assumption is that you have a free keyboard you can use... none?

Comment: Nope, no external keyboards, hence the difficulty haha

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the computer through SSH then this should work. (this is all on one line)

> sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -off -restart -agent -privs -all -allowAccessFor -allUsers